# Prevent insertion of extra space at line break

Tags: html, sublimetext, sublimetext3

When editing in a HTML document, I sometimes need to do a line break to do a line break for visual clarity.

Sublime is automatically inserting a blank space when doing this, how can I avoid this?

In editing mode:

```
<span>One short sentence</span>
<span>.</span>
```

Undesired result:

```
One short sentence .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a general feature of HTML. Whitespace, including line breaks, is significant between elements, and any sequence of whitespace is treated as equivalent to one space. So your code is equivalent to

```
<span>One short sentence</span> <span>.</span>
```

Thus, you need to find a different way to format your HTML source. If you really want to put adjacent elements on different lines in HTML source without causing a space character to appear, you can use a comment (comments are ignored, not treated as whitespace):

```
<span>One short sentence</span><!--
--><span>.</span>
```